# Bs4 not found in python3

Tags: web-crawler

I am trying to run a simple **scraper** script and I am receiving the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'` but  I did have it installed in my `python 3` lib. Why do I still see this error?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I was wondering if it has also happened to anyone else. Btw I have both paython 2.7 and 3.5 installed. I also have bs4 installed on both.